# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'audio_fadein'

Tags: python, cx-freeze, moviepy

I have used cx_freeze to build a python project into a single folder with an .exe and it's dependencies, but when I run the .exe I get the error:

```
AttributeError: module 'moviepy.audio.fx.all' has no attribute 'audio_fadein'
```

[image: AttributeError]

I have read the docs for MoviePy but cannot find out why this is happening. My Python program runs perfectly from within the IDE (PyCharm) but after compiling, I am getting the MoviePy error. I have used the recommended `from moviepy.editor import *`

I don't actually use the `audio_fadein` directly in my script, so it must be being called by MoviePy when I show my video. Here is the code:

```
def cherrybyte():
    pygame.display.set_caption('©2017 CherryByte™ Software')
    pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
    logo = VideoFileClip('CherryByte Logo.mp4')
    logo.preview()
    pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)
```

EDIT: I have now also tried changing the import statement to `from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip` but with exactly the same error.

Comment: I have no idea whether this is relevant, but using 'from moviepy.editor import *' isn't "recommended". Either just import moviepy.editor and prefix all the commands with that, or import only the things you need eg 'from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip'.

Comment: @Gloin It is exactly what is recommended by the creator of MoviePy - I have read the docs and been through the code, where it is also commented on being used that way. But you've given me something else to try which I'm grateful for so I'll try that tonight, thanks.

Comment: Ok, maybe when I said it wasn't recommended, I was being a bit strong. [Here](http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/getting_started/efficient_moviepy.html#should-i-use-moviepy-editor) in the docs, it states "if all you need is one or two features inside another library, it is better to import directly what you need". I agree, that often doing the bulk import is better, but I think for code for distribution, the selective import is preferred (its quicker to load, for sure).

Comment: Here is the commented code from within `moviepy.editor`:

`This file is meant to make it easy to load the main features of
MoviePy by simply typing:

>>> from moviepy.editor import *

In particular it will load many effects from the video.fx and audio.fx
folders and turn them into VideoClip methods, so that instead of
>>> clip.fx( vfx.resize, 2 ) # or equivalently vfx.resize(clip, 2)
we can write
>>> clip.resize(2)

It also starts a PyGame session (if PyGame is installed) and enables
clip.preview().`

But I will try the way you have advised, as it might somehow bypass the error

Comment: Ok, I changed the import statement to `from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip` which is all I need, the program executed with no errors, I built it to a single folder again, and tried to run the executable and got exactly the same error. This seems to be an issue with MoviePy perhaps? I have updated my question with this attempt.

Comment: Ok, I didn't really expect it to work, just pointing it out.

Comment: Yes its probably a moviepy error, try posting an issue on their [GitHub page](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/issues)

Comment: @Gloin: Thanks, I've posted it as an issue on their GitHub page. I'm just trying to add my short animated logo to my project, and MoviePy seems to be the most stable to use. I do have my animation saved as frames, so if I can't get this to work, I may have to try something with manually animating it or something.

Comment: @Jayce so did you find an appropriate solution?

Comment: I ended up building a list of `.png` frames and displaying them manually in order instead. I never did get to the bottom of this problem, and never used moviepy again. I already selected the answer for this post 4 years ago... This post is very old, I'm not sure why people are still commenting on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For everyone that has the same issue i solved it by modifying the selected  **init** file shown in the picture below:

[File Location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoxBq.jpg)

Inside it there is a piece of code that import every function inside the fx folder:

```
__all__ = [name for _, name, _ in pkgutil.iter_modules(
    fx.__path__) if name != "all"]
for name in __all__:
    exec("from ..%s import %s" % (name, name))
```

Comment this block and import manually every function needed, like so:

```
from moviepy.video.fx.accel_decel import accel_decel
from moviepy.video.fx.blackwhite import blackwhite
from moviepy.video.fx.blink import blink
from moviepy.video.fx.crop import crop
from moviepy.video.fx.even_size import even_size
from moviepy.video.fx.fadein import fadein
from moviepy.video.fx.fadeout import fadeout
from moviepy.video.fx.mirror_x import mirror_x
from moviepy.video.fx.mirror_y import mirror_y
from moviepy.video.fx.resize import resize
#etc.
```

Do the same with the init placed in moviepy.audio.fx.all

Answer (score 10):

I had same error while I was using the pyinstaller to build the .exe file.
However, I changed the import statement to `from moviepy.video.io.VideoFileClip import VideoFileClip`
and it worked.

Comment: other functions can be imported similarly https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/issues/591#issuecomment-965203931

Answer (score 1):

I solved the errror the same way HunterDev did.
Here is the complete code for:

Python 3.8.6\Lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\fx\all_*init*_.py

```
from moviepy.video.fx.accel_decel import accel_decel
from moviepy.video.fx.blackwhite import blackwhite
from moviepy.video.fx.blink import blink
from moviepy.video.fx.colorx import colorx
from moviepy.video.fx.crop import crop
from moviepy.video.fx.even_size import even_size
from moviepy.video.fx.fadein import fadein
from moviepy.video.fx.fadeout import fadeout
from moviepy.video.fx.freeze import freeze
from moviepy.video.fx.freeze_region import freeze_region
from moviepy.video.fx.gamma_corr import gamma_corr
from moviepy.video.fx.headblur import headblur
from moviepy.video.fx.invert_colors import invert_colors
from moviepy.video.fx.loop import loop
from moviepy.video.fx.lum_contrast import lum_contrast
from moviepy.video.fx.make_loopable import make_loopable
from moviepy.video.fx.margin import margin
from moviepy.video.fx.mask_and import mask_and
from moviepy.video.fx.mask_color import mask_color
from moviepy.video.fx.mask_or import mask_or
from moviepy.video.fx.mirror_x import mirror_x
from moviepy.video.fx.mirror_y import mirror_y
from moviepy.video.fx.painting import painting
from moviepy.video.fx.resize import resize
from moviepy.video.fx.rotate import rotate
from moviepy.video.fx.scroll import scroll
from moviepy.video.fx.speedx import speedx
from moviepy.video.fx.supersample import supersample
from moviepy.video.fx.time_mirror import time_mirror
from moviepy.video.fx.time_symmetrize import time_symmetrize
```

Python 3.8.6\Lib\site-packages\moviepy\audio\fx\all_*init*_.py

```
from moviepy.audio.fx.audio_fadein import audio_fadein
from moviepy.audio.fx.audio_fadeout import audio_fadeout
from moviepy.audio.fx.audio_left_right import audio_left_right
from moviepy.audio.fx.audio_loop import audio_loop
from moviepy.audio.fx.audio_normalize import audio_normalize
from moviepy.audio.fx.volumex import volumex
```

For more info check:https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/issues/591

Answer (score 0):

Actual code in `__init__.py`:

```
__all__ = [name for _, name, _ in pkgutil.iter_modules(
    fx.__path__) if name != "all"]
```

Just put square brackets around **[**`fx.__path__`**]**:

```
__all__ = [name for _, name, _ in pkgutil.iter_modules(
    [fx.__path__]) if name != "all"]
```