# Executable created via PyInstaller crashes

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I created a small app to download youtube videos and add them to my music folder so I can listen to them via spotify, app works fine as long as I run it via IDE.
I created an .exe file via pyinstaller, however it crashes on launch, I tried running it as administrator and also tried running it via cmd as people suggested in other threads, but nothing works.

I created it by using:

```
pyinstaller --onefile -c test.py
```

This is the python code:

```
from pytube import YouTube
from pytube import Playlist
from moviepy.editor import *
from pathlib import Path
import os

url = input('Enter URL: ')
ytd = YouTube(url)
stream = ytd.streams.first().download(filename= 'video') #stiahne do root filu
mp3_file = ytd.title + '.mp3' #meno pesnicky
#videoClip = VideoFileClip('video.mp4')
audioClip = VideoFileClip('video.mp4').audio
audioClip.write_audiofile(mp3_file) #mp4 na mp3
audioClip.close()
VideoFileClip('video.mp4').close() #v root file je mp3 a mp4
os.remove('video.mp4') #zmaze mp4, ostane mp3
file_path = str(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(mp3_file))) + '\\' + mp3_file
music_path = str(os.path.join(Path.home(), "Music")) + '\\' + mp3_file
Path(file_path).rename(music_path)
```

This is what I get one I try to run it via cmd:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rporu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_pkgres.py", line 13, in <module>
    import pkg_resources as res
  File "c:\users\rporu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 86, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg_resources.py2_warn'
[3296] Failed to execute script pyi_rth_pkgres
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while creating exe use the hidden import

```
pyinstaller --hidden-import=pkg_resources.py2_warn --onefile -c test.py
```

Comment: still it closes right away with: AttributeError: module 'moviepy.audio.fx.all' has no attribute 'audio_fadein'

Comment: this is a different bug, previous one was solved. change the import statement "from moviepy.video.io.VideoFileClip import VideoFileClip" like this check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44615249/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-audio-fadein

Comment: Please mark the answer as solved, is the new bug fixed now?