# i have a code that depends on pytube but when i try to converted to exe it does not work

Tags: python, youtube, pyinstaller, exe, pytube

I had been working on a code to download videos on python and it works perfect but when I tried to make it .exe for another computer it never runs the strong that I put to converter its `pyinstaller a.py` and I'm also using python 3.9
I just wanted to use the pytube in exe
I had seen just a little of people with the same problem but the one ly one that I saw made a mistake by putting the `pyinstaller -noconsole python.py` but I'm not putting that on there and I still don't get what the problem can someone help me, please.

```
from pytube import YouTube
import os, shutil
import subprocess
import tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog as tkFileDialog
import moviepy
import sys
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip
root = tkinter.Tk()

root.withdraw()
currdir = os.getcwd()

def get_mp3():
    qq=int(input("how many videos would you download: "))
    output = input("What format would you like it in (mp4/mp3)?: ")
    for i in range(0,qq):
        if output == "mp4":
            url = input("Enter a YouTube link: ")
            print("Chose a location")
            location = tkFileDialog.askdirectory(parent=root, initialdir=currdir, title='Please select a directory to download the video')
            yt = YouTube(url)
            print("Title: ",yt.title)
            print("Number of views: ",yt.views)
            print("Length of video: ",yt.length)
            
            print("Rating of video: ",yt.rating)
            ys = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()    
            print("Downloading...")
            ys.download(location)
        
            print("Complete")
            if i == qq:
                sys.exit(0)
            
    if output == "mp3":
        for x in range(0,qq):
            url = input("Enter a YouTube link: ")
        
            print("Chose a location")
            location = tkFileDialog.askdirectory(parent=root, initialdir=currdir, title='Please select a directory to download the video')
            print(location)
        
            mp4 = YouTube(url).streams.get_highest_resolution().download()
            mp3 = mp4.split(".mp4", 1)[0] + f".{output}"

            video_clip = VideoFileClip(mp4)
            audio_clip = video_clip.audio
            audio_clip.write_audiofile(mp3)

            audio_clip.close()
            video_clip.close()

            os.remove(mp4)
            shutil.move(mp3, location)  # Replace this with your own output directory


get_mp3()
```

Answer (score 0):

it actually all came to an end and all I had to due to its to change all of the **int** of the actual thing that was giving me the error so it was not about the pytube it was about the movie.py if someone also has the same thing as me and want to fix it here its the link and there just follow the directions and you will fix it :)
URL: [module-object-has-no-attribute-audio-fadein](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44615249/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-audio-fadein)